# Передача значения INPUT методом POST

Tags: php, html, post, input

пишу сайт в котором есть форма из 5 инпутов и одной кнопки. 
не понимаю почему данные с формы не отправляются на почту, да и вообще на сайте вываливается ошибка что данные не отправлены.. что я делаю не так??

p.s. php скрипт выполняется в терминале командой php -f bat.php , письмо при этом выполняется но без переменных:)

вот собственно код формы

```
<form action="bat/send.php" method="POST" name="form" class="rd-mailform home__form" >

<div class="form__group">
    <input type="text" class="form__control" name="name" placeholder="Ваше Имя*" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form__group">
    <input type="text" class="form__control" name="tel" placeholder="Номер телефона*" required="required">
</div>
<div class="form__group">
<input type="text" class="form__control" name="marka" placeholder="Марка машины">
</div>
<div class="form__group">
    <input type="text" class="form__control" name="model" placeholder="Модель">
</div>
<div class="form__group">
    <input type="text" class="form__control" name="age" placeholder="Год">
</div>

<div class="mfControls btn-group">
    <button class="btn" name="submit" type="submit">Оставить заявку</button>
</div>
<div class="mfInfo"></div>                                  

</form>
```

и есть так же обработчик

> send.php

с таким содержимым

```
<?php

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."class.phpmailer.php";

//if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$marka = $_POST['marka'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->From = 'site@salecar22.ru';
$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с сайта';
//$mail->FromName = 'Заявка с сайта';
$mail->AddAddress('ignatii19942310.ru@gmail.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->Body = "Имя: $name, Телефон: $tel, Марка: $marka, Модель: $model, Год: $age";


$mail->Send();
//}
?>
```

Comment: C локального компа вы вряд ли почту отправите... Нужно на реальном сервере запускать, либо настроить smtp-отправку.

Comment: всё находится на сервере)

Comment: Тогда что во входящем $_POST?

Comment: данные которые были введены в форме. если я правильно понял вопрос.. еще догадываюсь на счет того, что nginx всё отсылает на один файл и запрос собственно из-за этого не уходит /bat/mail.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишите что за ошибка вываливается...Вообще так должно работать:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['tel'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $tel = $_POST['tel'];
  $marka = !empty($_POST['marka']) ? $_POST['marka'] : '';
  $model = !empty($_POST['model']) ? $_POST['model'] : '';
  $age = !empty($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : '';

  $mail = new PHPMailer();

  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->From = 'site@salecar22.ru';
  $mail->Subject = 'Заявка с сайта';
  //$mail->FromName = 'Заявка с сайта';
  $mail->AddAddress('ignatii19942310.ru@gmail.com');

  $mail->WordWrap = 50;

  $mail->Body = "Имя: $name, Телефон: $tel, Марка: $marka, Модель: $model, Год: $age";

  $mail->send();
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь)  Ваш скрипт тоже работает) я сделал без использования phpmailer:)  А проблема была в том, что запрос не уходил на /bat/mail.php, т.к. у меня гвоздями было забито в nginx все отсылать на один файл, то есть на index.php.. в итоге я просто переписал конфиг под html а запросы php выполняет php-fpm